# Empty request when calling Laravel using Android Volley

Tags: php, android, laravel-5, android-volley

I'm trying to send some data from my Android app to a Laravel application. If I test the Laravel API using postman all the post data is received correctly. However, when calling the API from Android the Laravel application receives an empty request and the POST parameters are empty:

**Android:**

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.v("TAG",response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.v("TAG",error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user","ASDASDADSAS");
            params.put("pass","ASDASDADSAS");
            params.put("comment", "ASDASDADSAS");

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    };

    queue.add(sr);
```

Response:

```
<pre></pre><pre></pre><pre></pre>{"status":"500","data":[],"message":"**** parameter is either missing or empty"}
```

1, The 500 is hard coded, not something the server actually throws.

2, post data is received outside of laravel when creating a test.php file and echoing the $_POST.

**Laravel:**
- Route was added to csrf exceptions.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class APIController extends Controller
{

    public function postitems(Request $request){

      echo "<pre>";
          print_r($request->input('user')); // null
      echo "</pre>";

      echo "<pre>";
          print_r($request->all()); // null
      echo "</pre>";

      $rawPostData = file_get_contents("php://input");

      echo "<pre>";
           print_r($rawPostData); //null
      echo "</pre>";

     //handles request and api Call and gives response if all the data is present
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oké figured it out....

DO NOT include a trailing / in your URL or for some reason Laravel removes all Post Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please verify by executing the API in postman first as 500 is Internal Server Error.
2. If it is working then try to debug it from the backend.
3. You may add echo to print post parameters to verify it has been received properly or not.

Comment: 1, already done the 500 is hard coded, not something the server actually trows.
2, post data is received outside of laravel when creating a test.php file and echoing the $_POST.
3, they are empty